# how to address a color change in the following code

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to change a color in div class `bwg_back_0` through a CSS on webpage.

I'm trying something like this to adress it:

```
#bwg_container1_0 {
    color: #5fa5aa !important;
}
```

or

```
#bwg_container2_0 .bwg_back_0 {
    color: #5fa5aa !important;
}
```

What is wrong in this css?

[image: webpage code]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are having another style block at index line: 2421 that overrided your css.

You could try the following block that will have larger priority in browser (with an extra modifier, `div` in this case)

```
#bwg_container2_0 div.bwg_back_0 {
    color: #5fa5aa !important;
}
```

read more on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: As you said. Other .css have larger priority, but it comes from PRO version of photo gallery. I rly don't know how to overwrite this.

Comment: Kindly read more about the link, the priority is based on how many attributes is the rule matched the element, in your case both the `Other.css` and your css is using `#bwg_container2_0 .bwg_back_0` which both are matching one ID parent and the class, just add a simple `div` modifier will cause your rules have a higher priority

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
#bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg_back_0 {
        color: #5fa5aa !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo!! I got it :D

```
div#bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 .bwg_back_0 {
        color: #5fa5aa !important;
    }
```

I Add only div at start. It prioritize this css. Thx for this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity :)